# How to determine how many columns/rows a table copied from another application has?

Tags: excel, markdown, clipboard, evernote

I am trying to create a small tool to convert a table (copied with CTRL/CMD+C) from Evernote into a Markdown table.

Here is an example:

[image]

When I paste it into Excel it correctly shows columns and rows. When I paste it into an editor or read the raw clipboard all cells are seperated with an `\n`.

So how does Excel determine the count of rows/columns correctly?

Comment: I uploaded it via SO. It is just 3 columns and 5 rows all filled with the letters ASDF. it indicates that if all of them are seperated via \n it would be impossible to say how many rows/columns there are.

Comment: [It's very likely that Excel is seeing different data than your text editor is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_(computing)#Data_formats). You should probably look into whatever functions your OS provides to retrieve data from the clipboard and use them to inspect the contents. Pay particular attention to the data formats stored in the clipboard.